# Cant resolve rar dependencies in Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I'm having a problem fetching [active-mq](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-rar/5.15.6) in my gradle project.

It says `Could not find activemq-rar`

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-rar:5.15.6'
}
```

Even after adding the type

```
dependencies { 
  compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-rar:5.15.6@rar'
}
```

I remember I have hacked it by adding that dependency manually as an artefact in my Nexus 1 but now when migrated to Nexus 3 and its more strict I can't get this fetched. Any Ideas?

And Nexus 3 is not happy storing `rar` files at all.

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11712

Comment: What's the artifact's GAVEC coordinates reported by NXRM? You can check that by browsing to it your repository. If you're running NXRM 3.15 or later you will see a dependency snippet in the right panel that you can directly paste to your `build.gradle` file

Comment: I actually worked around that problem uploading it to my hosted 3rd party repo in nexus and turning off all of the validation on that particular repo. Still can't get it straight from Centra tho.

Comment: I feel a bit lost in your situation. Can you post the commands you run with outputs and logs from Gradle and NXRM? Are you pointing to a hosted or proxy repo? If proxy, what remote are you using? I just tried using this dependency without any issue both with Maven and Gradle pointing to my NXRM proxy pointing to Central.

Comment: Will let you know when I'm back to work Dawid. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this compoennt already in your NXRM repository? If so, since you're running v3.15+, you can simply navigate to the component in NXRM UI and in the right side panel there are dependency snippets that will help you how to include a component in your project. Also, make sure that your *build.gradle* points to the right repositories.

Here's the config I tried. NXRM proxy to Maven Central:
[image: NXRM Maven Central proxy]

A minmal *build.gradle*:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    maven {
      url 'http://localhost:2001/repository/maven-central'
    }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-rar:5.15.8@rar'
}
```

Then build your app `$ gradle build` shich should yield success and you should see the *activemq-rar-5.15.8.rar* in your repository.

[image: Usage snippet in NXRM 3.15+]

Comment: Yeah, it's in my repo but I needed to upload it manually, even when I have the proxy to central it seem to struggle to find it. Also Maven central provides a bad groovy DSL to this artefact I noticed.

After I uploaded it to nexus manually and disabled the strict validation, I am able to resolve the dependency with @rar qualifier.

THanks for looking into this.

Comment: @LazerBanan I didn't have to upload anything manually. I updated my answer to show all relevant config I used to pull _activemq-rar-5.15.8.rar_ from Maven Central via NXRM.